# Viewstate exceeded, but only in managed release version

Tags: visualforce, managed-package, viewstate

I have a VF page in my managed package, and QA noticed that the viewstate blows up if more than **200** records were selected on the previous page (it's part of a wizard). When I attempted to reproduce in my own org, I was able to select well over **1000** records without issue. After verifying that equivalent data is being used in both orgs, we have determined that the issue must have something to do with the managed package context, but I have no idea why that would be... The page displays a table of records, but all the columns are standard fields.

Also, when attempting to triage the issue with the Viewstate Inspector, I discovered that having it open breaks the page in a different manner: when selecting more than **50** records on the previous page, I get a terminal page complaining that one or more of the page parameters had an unexpected end of input.

**Question:** Does anybody know why simply being in a managed context would inflate my viewstate usage by more than 5x, or why the viewstate inspector open would tank my page params?

Below is the main markup of the page. I have also tried swapping the table with raw HTML, but to no avail...

```
<apex:form id="planActivationWizardFormId"> 
    <apex:pageBlock id="block">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="both">
            <apex:commandButton action="{! insertIncidentPlanRecordsForNonStagedPlans}" value="Next"/>
            <apex:commandButton action="{! cancel}" immediate="true" value="Cancel"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockSection collapsible="false" title="{! nonStagedPlanTableTitle}" columns="1">
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{! currentNonStagedPlanRecordSubsetList}" var="nonStagedPlanRecord">
                    <!-- Fieldset Fields -->
                    <apex:repeat value="{! planFieldSetList}" var="planField">
                        <apex:column value="{! nonStagedPlanRecord[planField]}"/>
                    </apex:repeat>
                    <!-- End Fieldset Fields -->
                    <apex:facet name="footer">
                        <apex:outputPanel layout="block" id="paginators" styleClass="paginators" rendered="{! (nonStagedPlanRecordListSize > defaultNonStagedPlanPageSize)}">
                            <apex:commandButton id="firstPage" value="First" action="{! nonStagedPlanTableController.first}" disabled="{! NOT(nonStagedPlanTableController.hasPrevious)}" rerender="planActivationWizardFormId" status="lockScreen"/>
                            <apex:commandButton id="prevPage" value="<Previous" action="{! nonStagedPlanTableController.previous}" disabled="{! NOT(nonStagedPlanTableController.hasPrevious)}" rerender="planActivationWizardFormId" status="lockScreen"/>
                            <apex:selectList size="1" value="{! selectedNonStagedPlanPageSize}">
                                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{! setNonStagedPlanPageSize}" rerender="planActivationWizardFormId" status="lockScreen" />
                                <apex:selectOptions value="{! nonStagedPlanPageSizeOptions}"/>
                            </apex:selectList>
                            <apex:commandButton id="nextPage" value="Next>" action="{! nonStagedPlanTableController.next}" disabled="{! NOT(nonStagedPlanTableController.hasNext)}" rerender="planActivationWizardFormId" status="lockScreen"/>
                            <apex:commandButton id="lastPage" value="Last" action="{! nonStagedPlanTableController.last}" disabled="{! NOT(nonStagedPlanTableController.hasNext)}" rerender="planActivationWizardFormId" status="lockScreen"/>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <apex:outputText escape="false" value="{! HTMLENCODE(nonStagedPlanTablePageOfCounts)}" />
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                    </apex:facet>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>   
</apex:form>
```

Comment: I don't, based on your description. However, perhaps a bit of your code could help me (or anybody else) give you a hint.